# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object./The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

For the longest time, my code has been running, but lately I encounter this error,`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I don't know if it is related to the creation and usage of a new database.

Here is my code:

```
con2.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT QtyInHand FROM Inventory WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productID;
    int existingQty = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Inventory SET QtyInHand=@QtyInHand WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@QtyInHand", SqlDbType.Int).Value = existingQty - int.Parse(quantity);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productID;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con2.Close();
```

Error on this part: `int existingQty = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

When I tried using my other SqlConnection: con

```
con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT QtyInHand FROM Inventory WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productID;
    int existingQty = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Inventory SET QtyInHand=@QtyInHand WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@QtyInHand", SqlDbType.Int).Value = existingQty - int.Parse(quantity);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productID;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

I encounter another error, `The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.` Error on `con.Open();` part. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, your `executeScalar()` call is returning a null value. Either refine your query - you can check your query by running it directly in your database - or change your logic to deal with null values.

For the second error, if calling `Open()` is throwing that error, it's because the connection object was in use before and was not closed properly. It's usually considered bad practice to reuse connections like that, so consider creating a new connection instance when you go opening one.

**Edit:** I tried to imply something in the second paragraph there, but now I feel I must make it explicit: don't forget to deal with the connection you left open there, as it may be a major performance hog for your application. Specially since it's an ASP.NET one. Dispose of connections as soon as you don't need them. When you call `Dispose()` for a connection, it gets closed - with the added bonus of other finer memory management procedures as well. Read about the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement and its usage with connections as soon as you have some time.